# docxtemplater using setData based on the value of another element

Tags: javascript, node.js, docx, phpdocx

I'm using the wonderful [docxtemplater](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater) for node, which is working perfectly.

However I want to be able to complete the template based on a value of a paragraph element on the page.

I've played around with various syntax styles but still can't seem to get the result I am after. Hopefully the code belows shows what I am trying to complete - apologies am fairly new with js.

```
<p id="text">Some text</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var loadFile=function(url,callback){
            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
        }
        loadFile("Letter.docx",function(err,content){
            if (err) { throw e};
            doc=new Docxgen(content);

            doc.setData(
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
            );

            doc.render()
            out=doc.getZip().generate({type:"blob"})
            saveAs(out,"Letter - Updated.docx")
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your template contained the text `Hello {name}`

You would have to write the following :

```
<p id="text">Some text</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var loadFile=function(url,callback){
            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
        }
        loadFile("Letter.docx",function(err,content){
            if (err) { throw e};
            doc=new Docxgen(content);

            doc.setData({
                name: document.getElementById("text").innerHTML
            });

            doc.render()
            out=doc.getZip().generate({type:"blob"})
            saveAs(out,"Letter - Updated.docx")
        });
    }
</script>
```